# And again Django can't find template (TemplateDoesNotExist)

Tags: django, django-templates

I found many topics with such problem, but can't solve my problem with it... So again, please, help to solve it.

Like I said, Django can't find template, but it exist in a "template" dir. And that dir also exist in my "settings.py".

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
#BASE_DIR + "/templates/",
)
```

As you can see, I tried two different ways. With no success... With all templates in that dir.

As I can see, there is no path to my templates folder in Error Log.

```
Template-loader postmortem

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
    /Users/slavaspirit/Documents/Django Tests/Test05/testapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/profile.html (File does not exist)
    /Users/slavaspirit/Documents/Django Tests/Test05/testapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/profile.html (File does not exist)
    /Users/slavaspirit/Documents/Django Tests/Test05/testapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/imagekit/templates/profile.html (File does not exist)
    /Users/slavaspirit/Documents/Django Tests/Test05/testapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/templates/profile.html (File does not exist)
    /Users/slavaspirit/Documents/Django Tests/Test05/testapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/allauth/socialaccount/providers/facebook/templates/profile.html (File does not exist)
```

Full settings list:

```
"""
Django settings for sisrosta project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-7g1@q9b&9ja@&xtuc%q7rk3(uon6z$lb2jr!9jcq84h2_c*fe'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

SITE_ID = 1

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'imagekit',
    'allauth',
    'taggit',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'article',
    'usercard',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False
    }
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sisrosta.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sisrosta.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'test.sqlite3'),
    }
}

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    #BASE_DIR + "/templates/",
)

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-RU'

TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

THE ANSWER IS:
Conflict between TEMPLATES and TEMPLATE_DIRS

Comment: ...what settings file are you editing?

Comment: What do you mean?) It's basic "settings.py" file in my project folder... Or you need to see all code from that file?

Comment: Do you have TEMPLATE_LOADERS ?

Comment: Actually, I don't have it. But in previous test applications, I never use it too, but all works just fine. Maybe, its because of Django 1.8 (previous tests was on Django 1.7)?

Comment: Yes all settings.py(without comments) could be helpful. Becuse with the information that you give, it seems that there is no problem.

And may you try to add  TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
    'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

Comment: I edit my post and add all data from my settings.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [Upgrading templates to Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/)

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            **Your TEMPLATE_PATH**,
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Thank you for this :) On can forget about stuff like that easy :P

Answer (score 0):

Please double check your template file path and file name. Maybe you can provide file structure of your django folder.

Here is my `settings.py` about template folder:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates','OMS'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates','CRM'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates','PMS'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates','BPS'),
)
```

and my template structure:

```
base_template.html  PMS
BPS                 CRM                 OMS
```

Comment: Hi, thx for answer. The structure is the same as my previous tests. Absolutley the same...

The most funny fact: I faced that problem in my Test02 app. And cant find the answer, why Django doesn't see that folder.

After that I just made another project with another Virtualenv and just copy settings code to new project. And all works fine!

But in that test app - same problem again!

Comment: Is your Test02 app folder structure the same as the other project you made? BTW, I found both TEMPLATES and TEMPLATE_DIR in your settings.py, are them conflict? I am not sure, I did not found TEMPLATES in my settings.py, I use django 1.7.4

Comment: Yes! That was the answer... As I see, TEMPLATES was created by Django 1.8... Because I works with 1.7 before, I didn't saw that change... My mistake, sorry and thx again...